# Show that $\cos(z)=z$ has a solution for some complex number $z$ (non-real)

Tags: complex-numbers

I've tried using the exponential form of cosine but the equation was harder than it seemed to solve. I've seen a solution on this site using a Picard Theorem but I don't have any knowledge of analysis yet (I am in high school). Is there a way to show this using elementary maths?

Comment: You won’t be able to find a closed form solution for the roots. The best to hope for is either some existence argument (for which Picard is likely to be the go-to tool) or find roots numerically. The latter is a more interesting route than you may expect, in particular the appearance of [Newton fractals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_fractal). That may be more appealing than the existence route.

Comment: you can show this with minimal analysis (and without Picard which is way too complicated a tool to use here) noting that $x -\cos x$ is non decreasing on the reals so it has only one zero at $x_0$, hence if $\cos z-z$ has only that one zero it would be $(z-x_0)e^{g(z)}$ for some nice (analytic) $g$ and looking at growth rates, $g$ is a linear function $az+b$ and then one gets contradiction by noting that $e^{iz}+e^{-iz}-2z=2e^{az+b}$ implies $a=i$ and $a=-i$ by taking appropriate limits with $z=ix, x \to \pm \infty$

Comment: There is no solution via elementary maths. But there is a closed Form via using the inverse of the [regularized incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) (see [dottie number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html)): [$\sqrt{1-\left(2\text{I}^{-1}_\frac12\left(\frac 12,\frac 32\right)-1\right)^2}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sqrt%5B1+-+%282+InverseBetaRegularized%5B1%2F2%2C+1%2F2%2C+3%2F2%5D+-+1%29%5E2%5D)

Comment: @KevinDietrich. There is an infinite number of solutions

Comment: I tried to stay as simple as I could. Do not hesitate to ping me if you need any clarification. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, should not it be kind of Intermediate Value Theorem or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using $z=x+i y$, expanding to cosine and isolating the real and imaginary parts, we have the two equations
$$\cos (x) \cosh (y)-x=0 \tag 1$$
$$\sin (x) \sinh (y)+y=0 \tag 2$$

The first equation gives
$$y=\cosh ^{-1}(x \sec (x))\tag 3$$ which, inserted in the second, would give (assuming $x>1$)
$$\tan (x)\sqrt{x^2-\cos ^2(x)} +\cosh ^{-1}(x \sec (x))=0\tag 4$$ which is impossible to solve explicitly even using special functions.

Graphing, what you could notice is that the $n^{\text{th}}$ zero of function
$$f(x)=\tan (x)\sqrt{x^2-\cos ^2(x)} +\cosh ^{-1}(x \sec (x))$$ are closer and closer to $2n\pi$. Using series expansion
$$f(x)=\cosh ^{-1}(2 \pi  n)+\frac{4 \pi ^2 n^2}{\sqrt{4
   \pi ^2 n^2-1}} (x-2 \pi  n)+O\left((x-2 \pi  n)^2\right)$$ giving, as an *approximation*,
$$x_n=2n\pi-\frac{\sqrt{4 \pi ^2 n^2-1} }{4 \pi ^2 n^2}\cosh ^{-1}(2 \pi  n)\tag 5$$ which, expanded again for large $n$, gives $$x_n=2 \pi  n-\frac{\log (4 \pi n)}{2 \pi  n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ leading to $$y_n=\log (4 \pi  n)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
Using $(3)$ and $(5)$ seems to give decent *approximations*
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 n & x_{\text{estimate}}& y_{\text{estimate}}& x_{\text{solution}}& y_{\text{solution}}\\
 1 & 5.8864994 & 2.5404479 &  5.8695604& 2.5448858 \\
 2 & 12.310739 & 3.2351074 &  12.308558& 3.2355041 \\
 3 & 18.657306 & 3.6372873 &  18.656748& 3.6373661 \\
 4 & 24.977015 & 3.9228865 &  24.976832& 3.9229079 \\
 5 & 31.284206 & 4.1447097 &  31.284142& 4.1447162 \\
 6 & 37.584491 & 4.3261473 &  37.584472& 4.3261491 \\
 7 & 43.880537 & 4.4796761 &  43.880536& 4.4796762 \\
 8 & 50.173780 & 4.6127518 &  50.173787& 4.6127514 \\
 9 & 56.465068 & 4.7301900 &  56.465078& 4.7301894 \\
 10 & 62.754935 & 4.8352824 &  62.754945& 4.8352818\\
 20 & 125.61973 & 5.5273581 &  125.61973& 5.5273579    \\
 30 & 188.46409 & 5.9325429 &  188.46409& 5.9325429   \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

We can do better in terms of approximations expanding $f(x)$ as a series around $x=2n\pi$ and continuing with power series reversion.

To make the results more compact, let
$$\color{blue}{m=2n\pi} \qquad \text{and}\qquad \color{blue}{t=\frac{\sqrt{m^2-1} }{m^2}\,\cosh ^{-1}(m)}$$ This gives
$$\color{red}{x=m-t+\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{P_k}{Q_k}\,t^k}$$ where the first polynomials in $m$ are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & P_k \\
 2 & 3 m^2-4 \\
 3 & m^4-14 m^2+20 \\
 4 & 25 m^6-240 m^4+528 m^2-320 \\
 5 & -3 m^8+179 m^6-1324 m^4+2816 m^2-1760 \\
 6 & -441 m^{10}+12537 m^8-86520 m^6+227376 m^4-251328 m^2+98560 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
and
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & Q_k \\
 2 & -2 m\left(m^2-1\right) \\
 3 & 3 m^2 \left(m^2-1\right) \\
 4 & 12 m^3 \left(m^2-1\right)^2 \\
 5 & 15 m^4 \left(m^2-1\right)^2 \\
 6 & 180 m^5 \left(m^2-1\right)^3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

which leads to much better estimates.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & x_{\text{estimate}}& x_{\text{solution}} \\
 1 & 5.8698165 &  5.8695604 \\
 2 & 12.308553 &  12.308557 \\
 3 & 18.656747 &  18.656748 \\
 4 & 24.976832 &  24.976832 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you! The approximation seems very good for large values of n. Could I ask what the O function means in your answer? Is it similar to the O from computer science?

Comment: @kelvin. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation